# How to decrypt PHP AES-256-ecb encrypted data using linux openssl?

Tags: linux, encryption, openssl, aes, php-openssl

I want to decrypt an AES encrypted json file using Linux pre-installed openssl command line tool, but I cannot figure out how to setup the correct flag of the openssl of Linux. The encryption code is provided by another party, so it cannot be changed. Because my environment does not support PHP, so I have to implement a Linux-version. Does anyone know how to solve the problem?

Below is the detail description of the encryption provided by another party and decryption process I implemented.

**encryption process**

```php
function openssl_encrypt_data($data, $cipher_algo, $key, $options = OPENSSL_RAW_DATA , $iv = NULL) {
    try {
        $encryptstr = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($data, $cipher_algo, $key, $options, $iv));
        return $encryptstr;
    } catch (Exception $e) {

    }
}

$aes_key = "b4396c8cd9b16b0d86604d6d3787bc12fe2af4c6401c23ec35db84d8392565b9190c0db1543e7be967240348d6d86d037e34042476509c786aa78dce706a620c";

// This is a super large json file. 
$original_data = '{
    "item": [
        {
            "submitId": "AG113560102",
            "submitDate": "2022-05-09 15:56:10",
            "age": "1",
            "workType": "12",
            "workTitle": "5", ...
            "agreeSales": true,
            "agreeScrivener": true}]}'

echo openssl_encrypt_data($original_data, "aes-256-ecb", $aes_key);
```

The script produces the following Base64 string:

> 7w2oNyAjBf1bCLQZTiOwUHM4O9ExakIdA8fQ0/Ls2ahRKPZ5WD1iHxshoBPLYGNxGi3IF2RZ5z2xHxTkb/SuJ5U5zYgYiiLaGObHCnMwudghUlaSo5dcgpHaycqoo8NuB8P3iDTWV+gGPif14ImxX/8rGJJBB5xZ0CdCYzKjhVsDDAbw2OozqOtEIkk9zk6uaNcsdomE7yzE17s1yL757N1PXm2JEEDgU+kxxRZzBEu9dBDswIQMsyy4mf0oKqB3yxVsybcTkoHAd/cCCCr1drI1/AolwktVbLlxiLVV1H79dr+Xom...

**decryption process**

```sh
openssl aes-256-ecb -d -K b4396c8cd9b16b0d86604d6d3787bc12fe2af4c6401c23ec35db84d8392565b9190c0db1543e7be967240348d6d86d037e34042476509c786aa78dce706a620c -in input.txt -out recover.json
```

The script, unfortunately, produces the following error:

> hex string is too long, ignoring excess
> bad decrypt
> 140157171651584:error:0606506D:digital envelope routines: EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length: crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:599:

I also tried the -nopad flag on the script:

```sh
openssl aes-256-ecb -nopad -d -K b4396c8cd9b16b0d86604d6d3787bc12fe2af4c6401c23ec35db84d8392565b9190c0db1543e7be967240348d6d86d037e34042476509c786aa78dce706a620c -in input.txt -out recover.json
```

The script ran successfully without raising error, but the recover.json file created cannot be load succesfully:

> recover.json is not UTF-8 encoded

I altered the flag to the -base64 flag, but it doesn't work, too.

```sh
openssl aes-256-ecb -d -base64 -K b4396c8cd9b16b0d86604d6d3787bc12fe2af4c6401c23ec35db84d8392565b9190c0db1543e7be967240348d6d86d037e34042476509c786aa78dce706a620c -in input.txt -out recover.json
```

> hex string is too long, ignoring excess
> bad decrypt
> 140157171651584:error:0606506D:digital envelope routines: EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt: crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:599:

None of the above script work. Does anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: Base 64 decode first?

Comment: Also, the key material is processed differently (the PHP side UTF8 encodes (or what is set), the OpenSSL side hex decodes). And AES-256 requires a 32 byte key.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I've tried to add -base64 flag to openssl as re-edited on the post. The flag doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Possibly due to the `echo` statement where you seem to try and echo raw binary. Not every byte represents a printable character. Instead, pipe the output to a file or something similar, or base 64 encode explicitly if you *require* text for some reason or other. Anyway, to understand encryption (which is generally defined as binary operations) you first need to understand *encoding* techniques (base 64, hexadecimals and the various character encodings such as UTF-8).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes The openssl_encrypt_data produced a Base64 encoded string, which is printable by PHP. BTW, the encryption PHP is the part that cannot change. It is provided by another party.

Comment: Seems more logical to create the decryption in PHP as well, no?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Thanks for your hint. I found that, in linux openssl, even though the AES Key provided after "-K" flag is in hexadecimal  format, it is converted to bytes underneath before the AES decryption. The PHP AES encryption/decryption takes the hexadecimal AES Key as utf-8 bytes without converting it to bytes using method like hex2bin. I solved this problem by treating the hexadecimal AES key as utf-8 bytes and using a python tool `binascii.hexlify` to encode it into a hexadecimal-encoded hexadecimal AES key and put it after the -K flag.

Comment: BTW, the encrypted base64 cypher provided after the `-in` flag need to have \n for every 64 character to allow large size cypher to be decrypted correctly.

Comment: Alright, glad you got it solved; feel free to self answer, happy to vote up if you place a comment below.

Answer (score 0):

After some discussion, I've come up with a solution. Below is the working decryption procedure:

1. Store the encrypted base64 text in a file input.txt
2. Open input.txt and make new line for every 64 characters and also make new line at the end (you can also using program to add '\n' for every 64 characters).
3. Store the hexadecimal aes key in a file called aes_key.txt.
4. Use a program (e.g., python) to open the aes_key.txt in uft-8 bytes and encoded it using hexadecimal encoding.

```py
with open('aes_key.txt', 'r') as f:
    aes_key = f.read().encode('utf-8')

import binascii
hex_encoded_hex_aes_key = binascii.hexlify(aes_key).decode('utf-8')

with open('hex_encoded_hex_aes_key.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(hex_encoded_hex_aes_key)
```

5. Use the string stored in hex_encoded_hex_aes_key.txt in the Linux openssl decryption command.

```sh
openssl aes-256-ecb -d -base64 -K <hex_encoded_hex_aes_key> -in input.txt -out recover.json
```